# Unique email constraint for django.contrib.auth.user

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, django-authentication

I have changed django.contrib.auth.user model where I have made the email id to be unique. After which I added a datamigration to reflect the same-

- python manage.py datamigration appname unique_password.
  Followed by python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto-->no changes. Finally, python manage.py migrate appname.
- Migrating forwards to 0003_unique_password
- appname:0037_unique_password.py

Now when I add a user whose email is not unique, it gives me an error and does not let me create the user through the **django admin**. But when i do:
>

- python manage.py shell
- from django.contrib.auth.models import User
- user=User('cust1','123','xxx@gmail.com')
  This creates a user object even though 'xxx@gmail.com' already exists.

How can I add an unique constraint to django.contrib.auth.user.email for an existing project (with data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checks for uniqueness occur during model validation as per the Model validation [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#validating-objects).  Calling `save()` on the model doesn't automatically cause model validation.  The admin application **will** be calling model validation.

Nothing prevents you from creating a `User` object in Python such as `user=User('cust1','123','xxx@gmail.com')` and then doing a `user.save()`.  If there are uniqueness checks at the database level, you'll likely get an exception at this point.  If you want to check before doing the save, call `is_valid()` on the Model instance.

If you want every `User` object to be automatically validated before save, use the [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) Django signal to do Model validation before the save proceeds.

Comment: thanks Austin ...but if i could do something more at the db level??!!

Comment: Your migration should have added the db level constraints.  Does your question imply that `User('cust1','123','xxx@gmail.com').save()` does *not* generate an exception when `xxx@gmail.com` already exists in the database?

Comment: yes. it does not create an exception. it just adds it to the db with those values :|

Comment: Interesting.  What db backend are you using?  Does the output of `manage.py sqlall` match the current structure of your database tables?  You should see a `UNIQUE` constraint in your database `CREATE TABLE` definitions.